# How to capture diacritics with keyPressed() in Processing?

Tags: unicode, processing, keypress

I am trying to emulate a typewriter in Processing, similar to [this one](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/27219).

Since I write mostly in Portuguese, I need the diacritics, which in typewriters is implemented as a non-advancing key (it prints the accent, and then the next key is printed under it, for example "pé pão pátria".

When I simply use the following line to print key values and codes, when I type `~`, even repeatedly, I get nothing, and when I type `~` + `a` I get only the `a`:

```
void keyPressed()   
    println("key: " + String.valueOf(key) + " value: " + int(key) + " code: " + keyCode);  
}
```

So the question is:

> How to capture diacritic accent keystrokes in a latin layout keyboard (french, spanish, portuguese), and how to compose unicode accented characters with from them?

Comment: What is the unicode value of the characters you're typing?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, I'm not sure how do write it, but for the "ã" I think it's U+00E3

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard is set to the correct language and the font support the characters, it should be possible to use those characters.

Here's an example based on the link you provided:

```
String text1 = " ";
PFont font;
int bfill = 150;
boolean randomizer = false;
 
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  smooth();
  font = createFont("Arial",48);//loadFont("Arial-Black-48.vlw");
  textFont(font, 20);
}
 
void draw() {
 
  background(bfill);
  fill(255);
  text(text1, 0, 40, width, height);
  if(randomizer) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 400; j++) {
      text1 += char(int(random(18, 126)));
    }
    text(text1, 0, 40, width, height);
    text1 = " ";
  }
   
}
 
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == BACKSPACE) {
    if(text1.length() > 0) {
      text1 = text1.substring(0, text1.length() - 1);
    }
  }
  else if (key == '1') {
    randomizer = true;
  }
  else {
    text1 += key;
    if(key == 'ă') println("got ă");
  }
}
```

[image: diacritics in Processing]

I simply changed the keyboard input to Romanian (which also has diacritics, such as ăâîșț).

I also see the message printed to the console as expected on the `ă` character:

```
got ă
```

**Update** Stackoverflow and Processing Forum user [GoToLoop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3769500/gotoloop) provided [a better solution on the Processing forum](https://discourse.processing.org/t/getting-accented-typed-chars-from-keys-like-e/43099) using [`keyTyped()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyTyped_.html).

Comment: On Linux in 2023, Portuguese Layout, I couldn't produce a "é" (or for that matter "àáãõê") using this code :(

Comment: Thanks to GoToLoop at https://discourse.processing.org/t/getting-accented-keys-like-e/43099/2 I found it all works if one uses `KeyTyped()` instead of `KeyPressed()`  :D

Comment: Nice! Totally missed your comment, but happy @gotoloop helped you get over the line: Great work! (I'm adding this note to the answer above)